# compare intersection of two datetime interval in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have two date time interval :

```
first stardate : 2014-06-20#00:01
first enddate  : 2014-06-24#23:59

second startdate : 2014-06-25#00:01
second enddate   : 2014-06-27#23:59
```

I can compare startdate < enddate with parsing to int 201406200001 < 201406242359

But I want to compare intersection of first date interval and second date interval.

First interval can be > or < second interval but these two intervals should not have any intersection.

How can I write this algorithm  in javascript ?

Comment: So, you want to check if these 2 intervals overlap?

Comment: On a high level, you can check if: first.startdate is between second.startdate and second.enddate OR  second.startdate is between first.startdate and first.enddate. If any of this is true, your dates overlap

Comment: Example : second startdate : 2014-06-23#00:01
second enddate   : 2014-06-27#23:59  it is false for me

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can compare them as numbers :

```
if( (start1 > start2 && start1 < end2) || (start2 > start1 && start2 < end1) )
```

This is true for overlapping intervals.

Basically, it checks if the start of the first interval is inside the second interval or if the start of the second one is inside the first one.

Comment: This does not handle the case where start1 = start2 or end1 = end2

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem, like this question proposes. I needed to grab this solution from another [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15807/what-is-the-shortest-possible-formula-to-find-the-intersection-between-a-set-of). I just adapted it to dates, as the question proposes.

Testing is easy. You can use the browser's console.

```js
function intercept(start1,end1,start2,end2) {
    return ( Math.max(0, Math.min(end2, end1) - Math.max(start1, start2) + 1) ) > 0
}

console.log('I should be true >> ', intercept(new Date("2018/01/01"), new Date("2018/01/05"), new Date("2018/01/05"), new Date("2018/02/03")))
console.log('I should be false >> ', intercept(new Date("2018/01/01"), new Date("2018/01/05"), new Date("2018/01/06"), new Date("2018/02/03")))
console.log('I should be true >> ', intercept(new Date("2018/01/01"), new Date("2018/01/05"), new Date("2018/01/03"), new Date("2018/02/03")))
```

Additional details: this code considers interception when intervals "touch" each other (like [1,2] and [2,4]). If you want to disconsider only touching, and consider only true overlap (like [1,3] and [2,4]), just remove the " + 1" inside the function. Suit yourself!

Again, applauses to the real [source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15807/what-is-the-shortest-possible-formula-to-find-the-intersection-between-a-set-of).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if those intervals overlap, this should do the trick:

```
var datesOverlap = (start1 < end2 && start1 > start2) ||
                   (start2 < end1 && start2 > start1);
```

Basically, if interval 1 starts before interval 2 ends, interval 1 may not start after interval 2, and vice versa.
(So, the start or end of interval 1 can not be between the start and end of 2, and vice versa)

This assumes you have the dates converted to `Date` objects, and you're comparing their numeric values.